# How can I get the y position of an item in an Android listview in the overriden 'getView' function?

Tags: android, listview, position

I have a customlist in which I overload the getView function and I need to know the y position of the current item that is being drawn. And I need it in relation to the entire list and not just the ones visible on screen. How can I find this out?

Edit: The Items have different heights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want the one relative to the top of the list (not the top of the visible screen, you can calculate it using:

```
int yPos = view.getHeight() * position;
```

Edit:
Different heights?  That probably hurts performance, since the recycler isn't helping much.

I don't think there's a magic method for this case.  Realistically what you have to do is keep an array of list position and y offsets, so for instance

```
// Item at position 0, top starts at 0, height is 15
pos[0][0] = 0
pos[0][1] = 15

// Next item starts one pixel down from previous item's top, is 10 pixels tall
pos[1][0] = 16
pos[1][1] = 10
```

And just populate from within getView.  Note that this solution tracks individual height as well as absolute offset for each item-  since the previous item's position + height is required to determine the next item's position.

Comment: I should have pointed out, that the items have different heights. I will add that.

Comment: I like where you are going with this, the problem is that when I display a list and some items are not visible (and therefore not drawn yet) then how could I get the height for these items?

Comment: This is an extension of ListView, right?  If you're talking about the ones you scroll down to, it's not a problem.  If you mean that, for instance, item 1 and 3 are visible, but 2 and 4 aren't, you'll just need to update as you go along.  What do you need this data for, anyway?

Comment: I am displaying a large list of database information, and I can skip part in the lists so there would be holes with missing heights in the array. I think I simply set the same size for all of the rows which might not be the most elegant solution but solves so many problems that its just better for now. I will revert to my current design later though and implement a version of your idea. Thanks for your help.